# Z-index not working (in codepen, maybe)

Tags: css

I have to admit that this one should be easy, but my brain can seem to work this on out. From my understanding of z-index. this codepen should work, but it's not and I don't know why. Is there a problem with codepen maybe?

https://codepen.io/mrowka3d/pen/bWZGWL?editors=0100

The above codepen has a center content and three smaller circles around it. the smaller circles should be underneath the bigger center circle. But I can't seem to get them to go under and I don't know why.

Just one of those days I guess :)

Thanks for taking a look

HTML:

```
<div class="infographic">
    <div class="infographic__callout infographic__callout-position1">1</div>
  <div class="infographic__center">
    <div class="center__title"><span class="center__serif-font">why</span> <br><span class="color2">companies<br> partner</span><br> <span class="center__serif-font">with</span> <span>PDAK</span></div>
    <div class="center__cta">Find out</div>
  </div>
  <div class="infographic__callout infographic__callout-position2">2</div> <!-- I even tried placing them before and after the center div -->
  <div class="infographic__callout infographic__callout-position3">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.infographic {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.infographic__center {
  width: 375px;
  height: 375px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  color: #4f2582;
  font-family: "Roboto", Tahoma, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.18em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  z-index: 20; /* this doesn't seem to do anything */
}

.center__serif-font {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.color2 {
  color: #16c1b7;
}

.center__cta {
  font-size: 80%;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.center__cta:after {
  content: ">";
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.infographic__callout {
  position: absolute;
  width: 186px;
  height: 186px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.infographic__callout-position1 {
  left: 65%;
  top: 23%;
  margin: -93px;
}

.infographic__callout-position2 {
  right: 70%;
  bottom: 30%;
  margin: -93px;
}

.infographic__callout-position3 {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -10%;
  margin: -93px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**z-index doesn't apply to static elements.**

Check here http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index

> This property specifies the stack level of a box whose position value
>   is one of absolute, fixed, or relative.

**Solution**

Add position relative to the `.infographic__center` class

codepen link .infographic__center https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmoLGz?editors=0100

**SNIPPET**

```css
.infographic {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.infographic__center {
  width: 375px;
  height: 375px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  color: #4f2582;
  font-family: "Roboto", Tahoma, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.18em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  z-index: 20; /* this doesn't seem to do anything */
  position:relative;
}

.center__serif-font {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.color2 {
  color: #16c1b7;
}

.center__cta {
  font-size: 80%;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.center__cta:after {
  content: ">";
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.infographic__callout {
  position: absolute;
  width: 186px;
  height: 186px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.infographic__callout-position1 {
  left: 65%;
  top: 23%;
  margin: -93px;
}

.infographic__callout-position2 {
  right: 70%;
  bottom: 30%;
  margin: -93px;
}

.infographic__callout-position3 {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -10%;
  margin: -93px;
}
```

```html
<div class="infographic">
    <div class="infographic__callout infographic__callout-position1">1</div>
  <div class="infographic__center">
    <div class="center__title"><span class="center__serif-font">why</span> <br><span class="color2">companies<br> partner</span><br> <span class="center__serif-font">with</span> <span>PDAK</span></div>
    <div class="center__cta">Find out</div>
  </div>
  <div class="infographic__callout infographic__callout-position2">2</div> <!-- I even tried placing them before and after the center div -->
  <div class="infographic__callout infographic__callout-position3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I never realized positioning effects z-index.

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` has the concept of the level in the HTML structure - as the `.infographic__center` a level deeper, in the HTML, then the other circle, it's 
 `z-index` range will be beneath the circle.

A simple solution is to add `position: relative;` to the `.infographic__center` class.

> **relative**: This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjusts the element's position, without changing layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned). The effect of position:relative on table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

[MDN CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=control)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Update this in css

```
.infographic__callout {
        position: absolute;
        width: 186px;
        height: 186px;
        border: 1px solid #cacaca;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```